# Consensus clustering with diceR package

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am supposed to perform a combined K-means + Gaussian mixture Models to determine a set of consensus clusters for a fixes number of clusters (k = 4). My data is composed of 231 cells from 4 different types of tumor which have a total of 19'177 variables (genes in this case).

I have never tried to perform this and I tried to follow the instructions from this R package : https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/diceR/html/consensus_cluster.html

However I must have done something wrong since when I try to run the code:

```
cc <- consensus_cluster(data, nk = 4, algorithms =c("gmm", "km"), progress = F )
```

it takes way too much time and ends up saying this error:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.0 Gb
```

So clearly my generated vector is too heavy and I must have understood things wrong in the tutorial.
Is someone familiar with diceR package and could explain to me if there is a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The `consensus_cluster` during it's execution "eats up" memory of R session. You have so many variables that their handling cannot be allocated in the memory.

So you have two choices: increase physical memory or use not full data, but its partial sample. Let's assume that physical memory increase is not feasible. Then you should use `prep.data = "sample"` option. However you'll need to wait. I model data and for GMM it was 8 hours to wait.

Please see below:

```
library(diceR)
observ = 23
variables = 19177 
dat <- matrix(rnorm(observ * variables), ncol = variables)
cc <- consensus_cluster(dat, nk = 4, algorithms =c("gmm", "km"), progress = TRUE, 
                        prep.data = "sample")
```

Output (was not so patient to wait):

```
Clustering Algorithm 1 of 2: GMM (k = 4) [---------------------------------]   1% eta:  8h
```